# Achieve effect of navigating without changing the current view

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, storyboard, ionic-framework

I have a UIWebView that imports a single page web app (ex. AngularJS app). When I navigate inside the webview, I want to make the user feel as if he's navigating inside a native app. To do this, I need to be able to programmatically change the navigation bar (title and the back button) and imitate page transition inside the app. The page transition can be done by using `ionic`, which uses hardware acceleration along with `velocity.js` but I am not sure if animating the fade in and sliding effect of navigation title would be easy enough.

Is there a way to programatically `animate` the navigation bar, as if you're moving away to a different view?